# Getting Excel data as CSV

Tags: java, excel, csv, io, jexcelapi

Please have a look at the following code. I am using `JExcel API`

```
import java.io.*;
import jxl.*;
import java.util.*;

class  ConvertCSV
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    try
    {
      //File to store data in form of CSV
      File f = new File("input.csv");

      OutputStream os = (OutputStream)new FileOutputStream(f);
      String encoding = "UTF8";
      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, encoding);
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

      //Excel document to be imported
      String filename = "C:/Users/yohan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ExcelTest/input.xlsx";
      WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
      ws.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
      Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(filename),ws);

      // Gets the sheets from workbook
      for (int sheet = 0; sheet < w.getNumberOfSheets(); sheet++)
      {
        Sheet s = w.getSheet(sheet);

        bw.write(s.getName());
        bw.newLine();

        Cell[] row = null;

        // Gets the cells from sheet
        for (int i = 0 ; i < s.getRows() ; i++)
        {
          row = s.getRow(i);

          if (row.length > 0)
          {
            bw.write(row[0].getContents());
            for (int j = 1; j < row.length; j++)
            {
              bw.write(',');
              bw.write(row[j].getContents());
            }
          }
          bw.newLine();
        }
      }
      bw.flush();
      bw.close();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
      System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

I do not want to write data into a CSV file, but I **MUST** load 'Fields' into a StringBuffer called "filedsBuffer" and load data into a StringBuffer called "dataBuffer" as comma separated values.

However, when I run this program, I get the following exception.

```
jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream
```

How can I solve this? If I can not do this with this API, please feel free to answer using a different API. Please help

Comment: Would you test with changing the file extension to .xls rather than .xlsx. It may help you.

Comment: Does jxl support xlsx format - Many questions and answers suggest jxl support old formats not xlsx?

Comment: @Jayan: Yes, may be..That why I updated it asking for different API if possible

Comment: JXL support xlsx but not fully I think. Have you tried different versions of your fil? For example save in older version of Excel?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: Yes, but it should support both. Not only for a version which is 10 years old

Comment: According to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/selenium-users/Nnp3WVlnnew looks like there is problem with versions newer than 2003. Can give a try with the answer of @Jayan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using [apache-poi](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html). It supports recent versions of ms-excel.  Here is code that could help to [get started](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ToCSV.java) -